# Use DataTable.Select() To Retrieve First 10 records only

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

### Scenario

I have a **ListBox** which has a DataTable linked as the DataSource in it and a Textbox **txtSearch** on whose "TextChanged" event the DataTable is searched for the matching records.

DataTable "Dt" has **20,000 records** saved in it.

### So Far

I am using the code below

```
DataTable DtSource = new DataTable(); //20,000 records in it
public void txtSearch_TextChanged()
{
    //Finds all records which have txtSearch's text in it
    DataTable Dt = DtSource.Select(" Name like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'");
}
```

The above code takes **more time** because it has to search all the records until it gets all the matched records.

**BUT**

I need only First 10 Matched records only

### Solutions from Internet

```
DataTable DtSource = new DataTable(); //15,000 records in it
public void txtSearch_TextChanged()
{
    //Finds all records which have txtSearch's text in it
    DataTable Dt = DtSource.Select(" Name like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'").Take(10);
}
```

### Problem

In the above solution it is once again searching through all **20,000 records** to get those **1,000 matched records** where **I only need the first 10 matched records only**.

I know it takes only few microseconds to execute this but still in my case this needs a performance boost.

Comment: Have you tried a [DataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: A *manual* loop that exits after 10 matches have been found won't do?